# Undefined reference errors when building fast map matching (FMM) tool with MinGW-w64

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw-w64, msys2, rtools

I am trying to build the fast map matching (FMM) tool on Windows using [this documentation](https://fmm-wiki.github.io/docs/installation/windows.html). The documentation talks about using Cygwin, but I chose to use MSYS2. Here are the details on what I have done so far:

1. Download **Rtools42** for Windows from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools42/rtools.html) and install it (I am using Rtools42 because I am creating an R package that provides an R wrapper for the FMM tool),
2. Search for **Rtools42 bash** shell using Windows startup menu and launch it,
3. Update **MSYS2** by typing `pacman -Syu` in the shell (relaunch the shell if it's closed),
4. Type `pacman -S msys2-keyring` in the shell to avoid invalid signature and corrupt database errors,
5. Install additional dependencies by typing the following command in the shell: `pacman -Sy mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc mingw-w64-x86_64-openmp mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake mingw-w64-x86_64-gdal mingw-w64-x86_64-boost mingw-w64-x86_64-swig mingw-w64-x86_64-python mingw-w64-x86_64-make`,
6. Launch **MinGW64 shell**: `C:\rtools42\mingw64.exe`,
7. Create a directory called **fmm** & make it the current working directory: `mkdir fmm && cd fmm`,
8. Clone git repo into the fmm directory: `git clone https://github.com/cyang-kth/fmm.git .`,
9. Edit **line 30** of **fmm/CMakeLists.txt**: `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)` (14 instead of 11; this change is needed for compatibility with the latest version of boost),
10. Create a new directory called **build** under fmm and make it the current working directory: `mkdir build && cd build`,
11. Create the **makefile** using **cmake**: `cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles" ..`,
12. Execute the makefile: `mingw32-make -j8`

The execution of makefile (without the `j8` option) produces the following error:

```bash
$ mingw32-make
-- CMAKE version 3.25.2
-- Set CMP0074 state to NEW
-- Set CMP0086 state to NEW
-- Set CMP0078 state to NEW
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 12.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 12.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/rtools42/mingw64/bin/cc.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/rtools42/mingw64/bin/c++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
--
No conda environment found in PATH!
PATH=C:\rtools42\mingw64\bin;C:\rtools42\usr\local\bin;C:\rtools42\usr\bin;C:\rtools42\usr\bin;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\progra~1\git\cmd;C:\rtools42\usr\bin\site_perl;C:\rtools42\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\rtools42\usr\bin\core_perl

-- Could NOT find Conda (missing: CONDA_PREFIX)
-- Non conda exist, search library in default path
-- GDAL headers found at C:/rtools42/mingw64/include
-- GDAL library found at C:/rtools42/mingw64/lib/libgdal.dll.a
-- Boost headers found at C:/rtools42/mingw64/include
-- Boost library found at Boost::serialization;Boost::exception
-- Boost library version 1_81
-- OpenMP_HEADERS found at
-- OpenMP_CXX_LIBRARIES found at C:/rtools42/mingw64/lib/libgomp.dll.a;C:/rtools42/mingw64/lib/libmingwthrd.a;C:/rtools42/mingw64/lib/libmingwthrd.a
-- Installation folder C:/Program Files (x86)/fmm
-- Not install fmm headers
-- Add python cmake information
-- Swig version is 4.1.1
-- Python header found at C:/rtools42/mingw64/include/python3.10
-- Python library found at C:/rtools42/mingw64/lib/libpython3.10.dll.a
<string>:1: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
<string>:1: DeprecationWarning: The distutils.sysconfig module is deprecated, use sysconfig instead
-- Python packages C:/rtools42/mingw64/lib/python3.10/site-packages
-- Using swig add library
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/build
[  1%] Built target CORE
[  3%] Built target ALGORITHM
[  9%] Built target CONFIG
[ 13%] Built target IO
[ 15%] Built target UTIL
[ 23%] Built target NETWORK
[ 26%] Built target MM_OBJ
[ 40%] Built target FMM_OBJ
[ 46%] Built target STMATCH_OBJ
[ 76%] Built target H3_OBJ
[ 78%] Built target FMMLIB
[ 80%] Linking CXX executable fmm.exe
C:/rtools42/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/fmm.dir/objects.a(fmm.cpp.obj):fmm.cpp:(.text.startup+0x26): undefined reference to `FMM::MM::FMMAppConfig::FMMAppConfig(int, char**)'
C:/rtools42/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/fmm.dir/objects.a(fmm.cpp.obj):fmm.cpp:(.text.startup+0x3c): undefined reference to `FMM::MM::FMMAppConfig::validate() const'
C:/rtools42/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/fmm.dir/objects.a(fmm.cpp.obj):fmm.cpp:(.text.startup+0x88): undefined reference to `FMM::NETWORK::Network::Network(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
C:/rtools42/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/fmm.dir/objects.a(fmm.cpp.obj):fmm.cpp:(.text.startup+0x9b): undefined reference to `FMM::NETWORK::NetworkGraph::NetworkGraph(FMM::NETWORK::Network const&)'
C:/rtools42/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/fmm.dir/objects.a(fmm.cpp.obj):fmm.cpp:(.text.startup+0xba): undefined reference to `FMM::MM::UBODT::read_ubodt_file(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
C:/rtools42/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/fmm.dir/objects.a(fmm.cpp.obj):fmm.cpp:(.text.startup+0xc7): undefined reference to `FMM::MM::FMMApp::run()'
C:/rtools42/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/fmm.dir/objects.a(fmm.cpp.obj):fmm.cpp:(.text.startup+0xd9): undefined reference to `FMM::MM::FMMAppConfig::print_help()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/fmm.dir/build.make:108: fmm.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:425: CMakeFiles/fmm.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2
```

How can I fix this?

**Update (2023-01-29)**

@Milan Š. asked me to edit `CMakeLists.txt` to include: `message(STATUS ${FMMGlob})` and `message(STATUS "EMPTY_LINE")` `message(STATUS ${NETWORK})` before the line `add_executable(fmm src/app/fmm.cpp)` and re-run cmake/make. Here's the output of running cmake:

```bash
$ cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles" ..
-- CMAKE version 3.25.2
-- Set CMP0074 state to NEW
-- Set CMP0086 state to NEW
-- Set CMP0078 state to NEW
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 12.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 12.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/rtools42/mingw64/bin/cc.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/rtools42/mingw64/bin/c++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
--
No conda environment found in PATH!
PATH=C:\rtools42\mingw64\bin;C:\rtools42\usr\local\bin;C:\rtools42\usr\bin;C:\rtools42\usr\bin;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\progra~1\git\cmd;C:\rtools42\usr\bin\site_perl;C:\rtools42\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\rtools42\usr\bin\core_perl

-- Could NOT find Conda (missing: CONDA_PREFIX)
-- Non conda exist, search library in default path
-- Found GDAL: C:/rtools42/mingw64/lib/libgdal.dll.a (found suitable version "3.6.2", minimum required is "2.2")
-- GDAL headers found at C:/rtools42/mingw64/include
-- GDAL library found at C:/rtools42/mingw64/lib/libgdal.dll.a
-- Found Boost: C:/rtools42/mingw64/lib/cmake/Boost-1.81.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found suitable version "1.81.0", minimum required is "1.56.0") found components: serialization exception
-- Boost headers found at C:/rtools42/mingw64/include
-- Boost library found at Boost::serialization;Boost::exception
-- Boost library version 1_81
-- Found OpenMP_C: -fopenmp (found version "4.5")
-- Found OpenMP_CXX: -fopenmp (found version "4.5")
-- Found OpenMP: TRUE (found version "4.5")
-- OpenMP_HEADERS found at
-- OpenMP_CXX_LIBRARIES found at C:/rtools42/mingw64/lib/libgomp.dll.a;C:/rtools42/mingw64/lib/libmingwthrd.a;C:/rtools42/mingw64/lib/libmingwthrd.a
-- C:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/mm/fmm/fmm_algorithm.cppC:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/mm/fmm/fmm_app.cppC:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/mm/fmm/fmm_app_config.cppC:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/mm/fmm/ubodt.cppC:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/mm/fmm/ubodt_gen_algorithm.cppC:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/mm/fmm/ubodt_gen_app.cppC:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/mm/fmm/ubodt_gen_app_config.cpp
-- EMPTY_LINE
--
-- Installation folder C:/Program Files (x86)/fmm
-- Not install fmm headers
-- Add python cmake information
-- Found SWIG: C:/rtools42/mingw64/bin/swig.exe (found version "4.1.1")
-- Swig version is 4.1.1
-- Found PythonInterp: C:/rtools42/mingw64/bin/python.exe (found version "3.10.9")
-- Found PythonLibs: C:/rtools42/mingw64/lib/libpython3.10.dll.a (found version "3.10.9")
-- Python header found at C:/rtools42/mingw64/include/python3.10
-- Python library found at C:/rtools42/mingw64/lib/libpython3.10.dll.a
<string>:1: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
<string>:1: DeprecationWarning: The distutils.sysconfig module is deprecated, use sysconfig instead
-- Python packages C:/rtools42/mingw64/lib/python3.10/site-packages
-- Using swig add library
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/build
```

And the output of running make (output is trimmed to not exceed SO's 30,000 characters limit):

```bash
$ mingw32-make
[ 34%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/FMM_OBJ.dir/src/mm/fmm/ubodt.cpp.obj
[ 36%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/FMM_OBJ.dir/src/mm/fmm/ubodt_gen_algorithm.cpp.obj
In file included from C:/rtools42/mingw64/include/boost/geometry/core/config.hpp:16,
                 from C:/rtools42/mingw64/include/boost/geometry/strategy/cartesian/side_by_triangle.hpp:27,
                 from C:/rtools42/mingw64/include/boost/geometry/strategies/strategies.hpp:137,
                 from C:/rtools42/mingw64/include/boost/geometry/geometry.hpp:57,
                 from C:/rtools42/mingw64/include/boost/geometry.hpp:17,
                 from C:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/core/geometry.hpp:15,
                 from C:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/network/type.hpp:17,
                 from C:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/network/network.hpp:13,
                 from C:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/mm/fmm/ubodt_gen_algorithm.hpp:14,
                 from C:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/mm/fmm/ubodt_gen_algorithm.cpp:5:
C:/rtools42/mingw64/include/boost/function_output_iterator.hpp:14:1: note: '#pragma message: This header is deprecated. Use <boost/iterator/function_output_iterator.hpp> instead.'
   14 | BOOST_HEADER_DEPRECATED("<boost/iterator/function_output_iterator.hpp>")
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ 38%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/FMM_OBJ.dir/src/mm/fmm/ubodt_gen_app.cpp.obj
In file included from C:/rtools42/mingw64/include/boost/geometry/core/config.hpp:16,
                 from C:/rtools42/mingw64/include/boost/geometry/strategy/cartesian/side_by_triangle.hpp:27,
                 from C:/rtools42/mingw64/include/boost/geometry/strategies/strategies.hpp:137,
                 from C:/rtools42/mingw64/include/boost/geometry/geometry.hpp:57,
                 from C:/rtools42/mingw64/include/boost/geometry.hpp:17,
                 from C:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/core/geometry.hpp:15,
                 from C:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/network/type.hpp:17,
                 from C:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/network/network.hpp:13,
                 from C:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/mm/fmm/ubodt_gen_app.hpp:14,
                 from C:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/mm/fmm/ubodt_gen_app.cpp:5:
C:/rtools42/mingw64/include/boost/function_output_iterator.hpp:14:1: note: '#pragma message: This header is deprecated. Use <boost/iterator/function_output_iterator.hpp> instead.'
   14 | BOOST_HEADER_DEPRECATED("<boost/iterator/function_output_iterator.hpp>")
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ 40%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/FMM_OBJ.dir/src/mm/fmm/ubodt_gen_app_config.cpp.obj
[ 40%] Built target FMM_OBJ
[ 42%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/STMATCH_OBJ.dir/src/mm/stmatch/stmatch_algorithm.cpp.obj
In file included from C:/rtools42/mingw64/include/boost/geometry/core/config.hpp:16,
                 from C:/rtools42/mingw64/include/boost/geometry/strategy/cartesian/side_by_triangle.hpp:27,
                 from C:/rtools42/mingw64/include/boost/geometry/strategies/strategies.hpp:137,
                 from C:/rtools42/mingw64/include/boost/geometry/geometry.hpp:57,
                 from C:/rtools42/mingw64/include/boost/geometry.hpp:17,
                 from C:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/core/geometry.hpp:15,
                 from C:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/network/type.hpp:17,
                 from C:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/network/network.hpp:13,
                 from C:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/mm/stmatch/stmatch_algorithm.hpp:12,
                 from C:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/mm/stmatch/stmatch_algorithm.cpp:1:
C:/rtools42/mingw64/include/boost/function_output_iterator.hpp:14:1: note: '#pragma message: This header is deprecated. Use <boost/iterator/function_output_iterator.hpp> instead.'
   14 | BOOST_HEADER_DEPRECATED("<boost/iterator/function_output_iterator.hpp>")
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ 44%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/STMATCH_OBJ.dir/src/mm/stmatch/stmatch_app.cpp.obj
In file included from C:/rtools42/mingw64/include/boost/geometry/core/config.hpp:16,
                 from C:/rtools42/mingw64/include/boost/geometry/strategy/cartesian/side_by_triangle.hpp:27,
                 from C:/rtools42/mingw64/include/boost/geometry/strategies/strategies.hpp:137,
                 from C:/rtools42/mingw64/include/boost/geometry/geometry.hpp:57,
                 from C:/rtools42/mingw64/include/boost/geometry.hpp:17,
                 from C:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/core/geometry.hpp:15,
                 from C:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/network/type.hpp:17,
                 from C:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/network/network.hpp:13,
                 from C:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/mm/stmatch/stmatch_algorithm.hpp:12,
                 from C:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/mm/stmatch/stmatch_app_config.hpp:16,
                 from C:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/mm/stmatch/stmatch_app.hpp:13,
                 from C:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/mm/stmatch/stmatch_app.cpp:5:
C:/rtools42/mingw64/include/boost/function_output_iterator.hpp:14:1: note: '#pragma message: This header is deprecated. Use <boost/iterator/function_output_iterator.hpp> instead.'
   14 | BOOST_HEADER_DEPRECATED("<boost/iterator/function_output_iterator.hpp>")
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ 46%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/STMATCH_OBJ.dir/src/mm/stmatch/stmatch_app_config.cpp.obj
In file included from C:/rtools42/mingw64/include/boost/geometry/core/config.hpp:16,
                 from C:/rtools42/mingw64/include/boost/geometry/strategy/cartesian/side_by_triangle.hpp:27,
                 from C:/rtools42/mingw64/include/boost/geometry/strategies/strategies.hpp:137,
                 from C:/rtools42/mingw64/include/boost/geometry/geometry.hpp:57,
                 from C:/rtools42/mingw64/include/boost/geometry.hpp:17,
                 from C:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/core/geometry.hpp:15,
                 from C:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/network/type.hpp:17,
                 from C:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/network/network.hpp:13,
                 from C:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/mm/stmatch/stmatch_algorithm.hpp:12,
                 from C:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/mm/stmatch/stmatch_app_config.hpp:16,
                 from C:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/mm/stmatch/stmatch_app_config.cpp:5:
C:/rtools42/mingw64/include/boost/function_output_iterator.hpp:14:1: note: '#pragma message: This header is deprecated. Use <boost/iterator/function_output_iterator.hpp> instead.'
   14 | BOOST_HEADER_DEPRECATED("<boost/iterator/function_output_iterator.hpp>")
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ 46%] Built target STMATCH_OBJ
[ 48%] Building C object CMakeFiles/H3_OBJ.dir/third_party/h3/lib/algos.c.obj
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/H3_OBJ.dir/third_party/h3/lib/baseCells.c.obj
[ 51%] Building C object CMakeFiles/H3_OBJ.dir/third_party/h3/lib/bbox.c.obj
[ 53%] Building C object CMakeFiles/H3_OBJ.dir/third_party/h3/lib/coordijk.c.obj
[ 55%] Building C object CMakeFiles/H3_OBJ.dir/third_party/h3/lib/faceijk.c.obj
[ 57%] Building C object CMakeFiles/H3_OBJ.dir/third_party/h3/lib/geoCoord.c.obj
[ 59%] Building C object CMakeFiles/H3_OBJ.dir/third_party/h3/lib/h3Index.c.obj
[ 61%] Building C object CMakeFiles/H3_OBJ.dir/third_party/h3/lib/h3UniEdge.c.obj
[ 63%] Building C object CMakeFiles/H3_OBJ.dir/third_party/h3/lib/linkedGeo.c.obj
[ 65%] Building C object CMakeFiles/H3_OBJ.dir/third_party/h3/lib/localij.c.obj
[ 67%] Building C object CMakeFiles/H3_OBJ.dir/third_party/h3/lib/mathExtensions.c.obj
[ 69%] Building C object CMakeFiles/H3_OBJ.dir/third_party/h3/lib/polygon.c.obj
[ 71%] Building C object CMakeFiles/H3_OBJ.dir/third_party/h3/lib/vec2d.c.obj
[ 73%] Building C object CMakeFiles/H3_OBJ.dir/third_party/h3/lib/vec3d.c.obj
[ 75%] Building C object CMakeFiles/H3_OBJ.dir/third_party/h3/lib/vertex.c.obj
[ 76%] Building C object CMakeFiles/H3_OBJ.dir/third_party/h3/lib/vertexGraph.c.obj
[ 76%] Built target H3_OBJ
[ 78%] Linking CXX shared library libFMMLIB.dll
[ 78%] Built target FMMLIB
[ 80%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/fmm.dir/src/app/fmm.cpp.obj
In file included from C:/rtools42/mingw64/include/boost/geometry/core/config.hpp:16,
                 from C:/rtools42/mingw64/include/boost/geometry/strategy/cartesian/side_by_triangle.hpp:27,
                 from C:/rtools42/mingw64/include/boost/geometry/strategies/strategies.hpp:137,
                 from C:/rtools42/mingw64/include/boost/geometry/geometry.hpp:57,
                 from C:/rtools42/mingw64/include/boost/geometry.hpp:17,
                 from C:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/core/geometry.hpp:15,
                 from C:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/network/type.hpp:17,
                 from C:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/network/network.hpp:13,
                 from C:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/mm/fmm/fmm_algorithm.hpp:13,
                 from C:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/mm/fmm/fmm_app_config.hpp:16,
                 from C:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/mm/fmm/fmm_app.hpp:14,
                 from C:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/app/fmm.cpp:10:
C:/rtools42/mingw64/include/boost/function_output_iterator.hpp:14:1: note: '#pragma message: This header is deprecated. Use <boost/iterator/function_output_iterator.hpp> instead.'
   14 | BOOST_HEADER_DEPRECATED("<boost/iterator/function_output_iterator.hpp>")
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ 82%] Linking CXX executable fmm.exe
C:/rtools42/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/fmm.dir/objects.a(fmm.cpp.obj):fmm.cpp:(.text.startup+0x26): undefined reference to `FMM::MM::FMMAppConfig::FMMAppConfig(int, char**)'
C:/rtools42/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/fmm.dir/objects.a(fmm.cpp.obj):fmm.cpp:(.text.startup+0x3c): undefined reference to `FMM::MM::FMMAppConfig::validate() const'
C:/rtools42/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/fmm.dir/objects.a(fmm.cpp.obj):fmm.cpp:(.text.startup+0x88): undefined reference to `FMM::NETWORK::Network::Network(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
C:/rtools42/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/fmm.dir/objects.a(fmm.cpp.obj):fmm.cpp:(.text.startup+0x9b): undefined reference to `FMM::NETWORK::NetworkGraph::NetworkGraph(FMM::NETWORK::Network const&)'
C:/rtools42/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/fmm.dir/objects.a(fmm.cpp.obj):fmm.cpp:(.text.startup+0xba): undefined reference to `FMM::MM::UBODT::read_ubodt_file(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
C:/rtools42/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/fmm.dir/objects.a(fmm.cpp.obj):fmm.cpp:(.text.startup+0xc7): undefined reference to `FMM::MM::FMMApp::run()'
C:/rtools42/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/fmm.dir/objects.a(fmm.cpp.obj):fmm.cpp:(.text.startup+0xd9): undefined reference to `FMM::MM::FMMAppConfig::print_help()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/fmm.dir/build.make:108: fmm.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:425: CMakeFiles/fmm.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2
```

**Update (2023-02-05)**

@Milan Š. actually meant to add `${NetworkGlob}` instead of `${NETWORK}` to `CMakeLists.txt`. The output of cmake changed slightly (only showing the diff and the context rows):

```bash
...
-- EMPTY_LINE
-- C:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/network/bidirectional_network_graph.cppC:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/network/network.cppC:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/network/network_graph.cppC:/Users/ashir/Documents/testing/fmm/fmm/src/network/rtree.cpp
-- Installation folder C:/Program Files (x86)/fmm
...
```

The output of running make is unchanged.

Comment: Should probably report this to the developers.

Comment: What's rtools? Did you try the normal MSYS2?

Comment: Stack Overflow discourages using **images** for represent an error message. I would expect a user with over 1500 reputation to be aware of that policy, which is noted even in [ask].

Comment: Please do not post links to the `.exe` file that you used. I don't want to download a random binary from a link that I blindly click on.

Comment: I've also noticed that you are missing some additional dependencies:
`libexpat1-devel libbz2-devel zlib-devel` which I do not see you installing in step 5. Do you already have these? Judging by the authors `CMakeLists.txt` and the error it seems to me that the `FMM_OBJ` target is not building and thus can't be linked against other targets. Run this without `-j8` the message will probably make more sense then and please: **post the text** not the **image** after you run it without `-j8`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, I thought of creating an issue on GitHub (where this project is hosted), but noticed that the developer is not very active there. So, I thought I would ask the SO community for help.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, you can find about rtools here: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools42/rtools.html; Good idea, let me try using the normal MSYS2 and see if the program compiles successfully.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, thanks for pointing this out! I may have overlooked this. Will be careful from next time onwards.

Comment: @MilanŠ., thanks, I have replaced the installer link with the download instruction page.

Comment: Do not wait for the next question. Fix the current one: Replace the image with the text it represents.

Comment: @Ashirwad before yoy replace the text run it without `-j8` as I wrote in the comment please.

Comment: While you're in mingw64 and installed x64 toolchain, the final makefile is w32 thus wouldn't work. Never dealt with fmm, you may either try to generate a mingw64 ready makefile or start from ming32.exe shell, install w32 build chains and try to build.

Comment: @Chris.C, the make utility that gets installed for mingw64 is called mingw32-make. Please see this: https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-make

Comment: @MilanŠ., please take a look at the error message now.

Comment: @Ashirwad delete the build folder, then edit the `CMakeLists.txt` to include: `message(STATUS ${FMMGlob})` and `message(STATUS "EMPTY_LINE")` `message(STATUS ${NETWORK})` before the line `add_executable(fmm src/app/fmm.cpp)`. Re-run the cmake/make and post the output of that into another edit please.

Comment: @MilanŠ., please take a look at update.

Comment: @Ashirwad I apologize, this was my mistake but instead of `${NETWORK}` I wanted to write `${NetworkGlob}`. However to at least explain what I'm trying to do here. I'm trying to figure out why there are undefined references to the authors "NETWORK object library". If during `make` the target isn't even being built then that is the most probable explanation. If you edit it and the `${NetworkGlob}` is empty then it is the reason. This however is most likely something the author has to fix. If I'll have the time I'll try to get the same environment as you and look at it more.

Comment: @MilanŠ., please take a look at the update that I have added. Also, I would be really grateful if you could try reproducing the problem at your end and see what's going wrong.

Comment: @MilanŠ., did you get a chance to look at the update that I added?

Comment: @Ashirwad no I did not, this question would require me to (as you mentioned in the Feb 6 comment) try and reproduce the problem so I could fix it. And I currently don't have enough time to do so. I'll get to it if I get the time, but I don't know when.